# Mono under Jboss

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jboss, mono

I would just like to know if it is possible to run MONO ASP.NET MVC under JBOSS? And if so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That makes no sense.  JBoss is a Java app server. Mono is .NET.  They are distinct alternatives. You don't run one of them "under" another.   So... The answer to your question is **No.**

Comment: I thought that because mono can run on Apache and Apache is an integral part of Jboss...

Comment: Apache is not an integral part of JBoss.

Comment: @Dejan: Apache is an organisation, not a piece of software. Also, JBoss (which is also an organisation) and Apache have nothing whatsoever to do with each other.

Answer (score 7):

Mainsoft sells a product that recompiles .NET code into Java code that can be hosted inside a J2EE server.

You can check their offering here: http://www.mainsoft.com/